# The Fibonacci runner code: JAVA

Tags: java

Lab Description : Generate a Fibonacci sequence. Each number in the Fibonacci sequence is the sum of the two preceding numbers in the sequence. The first two numbers in the sequence are both 1. The third number is 2 , the fourth number is 3, the fifth number is 5, and the sixth number is 8. The program should be able to return a specified number in the fibo sequence. If a number is specified that is out of range, a -1 should be returned.

I have the hard math code done below, with no error:

```
public class Fibonacci
{
    int[] fibArray;
    public Fibonacci()
    {
        fibArray = new int[50];
        this.setFibo();
    }
    public void setFibo()
    {
        fibArray[0]=1;
        fibArray[1]=1;
        for(int idx = 2; idx<fibArray.length; idx++){
            fibArray[idx] = fibArray[idx-1] + fibArray[idx-2];
        }
    }
    public int[] getFibo()
    {
        return fibArray;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.getFibo() + "\n";
    }
}
```

And below I'm having trouble with the runner:

```
public class FibonacciRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] fibArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,11,16,21,31,41,46,1,1,2,1,2,11};
        Fibonacci fibo = new Fibonacci();
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());

    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do? getFibo() return the array itself. To get the value associated to the element you should access it. something like: `getFibo()[34]`.

Comment: could you provide an example of what the correct output you are looking for is?

Comment: I'm not certain what you are asking, but I suspect [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22051794/2970947) may help.

Answer (score 1):

The question is bit clear, your implementation is not clear either. If you need to get a specific number from the Fibonacci sequence the getFibo() should return and int and not int[]. Also, the getFibo should take the value/index as in, getFibo(int value). Please specify the requirement clearly, with an example. You may refer the code below.

```
public int getFibo(int index)
{
    if(index < 50)
     return fibArray[index];
    else
      return -1;
}
```